# Why the code in controller are called twice?

Tags: angularjs, ionic-framework

There is the following code in the html file `templates\events.html`.

```
<div class="events-2colmn-l backgnd-cover" ui-sref="menu.music">
    MUSIC
</div>
```

In route.js

```
  .state('menu.music', {
    url: '/music',
    views: {
      'side-menu21': {
        templateUrl: 'templates/music.html',
        controller: 'musicCtrl'
      }
    }
  })
```

And in the controller there is

```
.controller('musicCtrl', function ($scope, EventService) { // called twice when clicked
    var allEvents = EventService.query({ category: "Music" });
    allEvents.$promise.then(function (response) { 
        $scope.events = response;  
    });
})
```

The code in the controller is always called twice when the `<div ...>MUSIC</div>` is touched. How to make sure it's only called once when clicked?

Comment: Does this happens in other parts of your application? Place some logs or breakpoints in other controllers just to be sure.

Comment: Do a search for 'musicCtrl' in your whole app and make sure you dont have duplicate controllers like an ng-controller on the events.html

Comment: @Srijith I searched and there is only one `musicCtrl` controller, one template music.html file has `ng-controller="musicCtrl"`

Comment: @ItaloAyres There are some other items similar to "music" and they have the same issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should have the controller associated with the html either through the ng-controller or in your states in app.js.

So when you have your state like this

```
.state('menu.music', {
 url: '/music',
 views: {
  'side-menu21': {
    templateUrl: 'templates/music.html',
    controller: 'musicCtrl'
   }
  }
})
```

you dont need the ng-controller in your music.html. Thats what is causing the controller being called twice. Try removing the ng-controller and verify

Comment: Thanks a lot. BTW, which way is better practice? (route vs ng-controller)

Comment: I usually have them in the html so people know which controller is used in the html without having to check the routes, but its a personal preference. Not aware of any reasons why one would choose either.

Answer (score 3):

It is because your controller is being called twice...

- Once when you are calling
- And the second time when the templates/music.html is called because you must be using ng-controller directive in music.html as well...kindly check